# display 2nd form depending on 1st form result

Tags: forms, tapestry

I have two form in the same Tapestry page's:

First one is composed of :

- select
- submit button.

If there is a valid result I display it.

Otherwise I want to display the 2nd form wich is composed of :

- 4 textfields
- 1 submit button

So the 2nd must not be displayed first time, but only in case of empty result from the 1st one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: Please share what you have tried so far.

Second: You can do this in a number of ways. The easiest is just to use a

```
<form>
  <t:if test="showFirstForm">
     ....your 1st form content ....
    <p:else>
         ....your 2nd form content ....
    <p:else>
  </t:if>
</form>
```

You might also like to have a look at the [FormFragment](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/FormFragment.html) for ajax controlled dynamic form content using triggers to redraw.

Comment: Thank you a lot @joostschouten FormFragment works better for me :) !